# Web-разработка на java

Tags: java

я изучаю язык java  с нуля и хочу перейти в разработку веб-приложений на java(думаю знаний java языка хватает уже). Но не знаю, с чего начать и как приступиться к этому. Можете объяснить, как в наши дни создают веб-приложения на языке java, какие технологии используют, подкиньте источников,  с которых можно познавать это ремесло(книги может какие). В интернете везде конфигурируют три понятия: Servlets, Spring boot и Spring MVC, но я не понимаю, что для чего нужно, поэтому прошу объяснить, как делают Front и Back end на java.

Comment: Spring **boob** это что-то рядом с языком программирования СиСи+. Ну если вся мощь интернета не помогла вам разобраться в этих понятия, то как ещё один ресурс в этом поможет? Вам нужен частный преподаватель

Comment: Когда я прочитал заголовок "Web-разработка на java", то я решил сразу остановиться...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну это достаточно сложный разговор.

Основы сетевого взаимодействия двух компьютеров состоят в том, что ваш компьютер может слушать некоторый порт и при поступлении данных на него отвечать по сетевым протоколам обратно. Для интернет обычно используется HTTP протокол и в Java в простейшем случае реализованы сервер HttpServer и клиент HttpClient.

Но это не наш путь, это слишком низкий уровень. На основе этого было создано много всяких умных спецификация под общим названием JakartaEE (JavaEE) и готовых программных продуктов с поддержкой этих самых спецификаций и описывающих как пользоваться этим всем. В итоге мы имеем кучу веб-серверов приложений разной степени сложности и возможностей: Spring, Tomcat, WildFly, GlassFish, WebSphere и другие. И работающие на этом всем контейнеры c приложениями (сервлеты), которые мы им подпихиваем и пользуемся их возможностями.

Несмотря на то, что они используют общие принципы JakartaEE, в тоже время серверы приложений отличаются друг от друга и потому у вас куча путей, куда можно развиваться и что на них можно делать.

Можете сначала глянуть на простой JSP с Tomcat: https://metanit.com/java/javaee/
Потом можете попробовать Apache Struts: https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/index.html
Ну или можете сразу начать со Spring MVC: [https://java-master.com/spring-mvc-первое-веб-приложение/](https://java-master.com/spring-mvc-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/)

В любом случае лучше найти какой-нибудь законченный цикл уроков, поскольку тема достаточно сложная и включает в себя много различной информации. Ну и да, тема оффтопик из-за этого и порождает споры, как лучше это все разгребать и куда двигаться сначала.